# Filter Phone numbers with Angular js

Tags: angularjs, filter, angular-filters

I have many phone numbers formats in a json file, how can i do a search filter that will find the right numbers?

Search input number: +14181231234

In my json each number can be formated this way.

```
(418) 1231234
418-123-1234
+14181231234
418 123 1234
```

Comment: I did find i way but i want to add to this regex `[+()-\s]/g` all number beginning with +1 and +0 http://plnkr.co/edit/gB7LF0As0G6NOmXnBJvh